# Lua global table available from another lua script

Tags: lua, global

How to get access to table saved by another lua script with its unique name?

I tried to use in one script like:

_G.Value =12345 or
_G["Value"]=12345

in the other script it does not read:

_G.Value or
_G["Value"]

Is there any other way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the environment? in some cases scripts exist in their own `sandbox` unable to "interfere" with other executing scripts' states.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access a global variable from another file, place `require "firstfile.lua"` in the top of the second file. This will work for _G or any other variable.

My code:

```
--file 1, "l1.lua"
value = "A"
print(_G.value)
--file 2, "l2.lua"
require "l1"
print(_G.value)
```

Executing lua l2.lua produces:

```
A
A
```

(One "A" for each print line in each file)